# Syntax error in mysqldump command

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
mysqldump mydatabase < /my/path/to/sqlfile.sql;
```

This is my command issued. What could be the cause of this syntax error, i'm pretty sure its correct.

I am trying to load an sql file to my database.

Comment: Plese check the syntax in my answer!

Comment: It would be nice to accept the most-upvoted answer!

Answer (score 8):

use

> mysqldump -u username -p databasename > filename.sql

to export 
and

> mysql -u username -p databasename < filename.sql

to import

Please refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 2):

Synatax of MySQL dump command is : mysqldump -u  -p  >

In your case if the username is root then : mysqldump -u root -p mydatabase > /my/path/to/sqlfile.sql;

Answer (score 1):

This might work out!

```
backup: # mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql

restore:# mysql -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] < dumpfilename.sql
```

example

```
mysql -u root -ptmppassword databaseName < /tmp/fileName.sql
```