# Backup clearDB database to local

Tags: mysql, cleardb

I am trying to backup and restore the cleardb database. I was trying to backup to my local computer first and then restore it. However, I am not able to create a backup

```
   mysqldump -h us-csdr-fern-sds-03.cleardb.net -u sdloremipsum5 -p ipsum <my_dev_dump.sql
```

I am trying this from mysql shell but I get

> Syntax Error: Unexpected Identifier

Answer (score 0):

use

```
mysqldump -u username -p databasename > filename.sql
```

to export and

```
mysql -u username -p databasename < filename.sql
```

to import

Please refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html

Duplicate: [Syntax error in mysqldump command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502556/syntax-error-in-mysqldump-command)
Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18502626/10368530

Comment: I got the same error. I think I have to enter the host name though because my mysql database is not in my computer and is hosted in cleardb